# Finding mean and variance in R

Tags: r, statistics, mean, variance, die

Is what I did correct in making a code for this problem?

My goal is to find the mean and variance of the total score of the team when for any pair of gamers who throw the same number, the team scores 1 point.

```
die <- function(n){sample(1:6, n, replace = TRUE)}

A <- function(Die){
  int <- table(Die)
  sum(as.integer(int/2))
}

rolls <- 10000
players <- 10
scoreA <- sapply(1:rolls, function(x) {
  rolled <- die(players)
  A(rolled)
})

mean(scoreA)
var(scoreA)
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQh78.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick mental run through the problem should tell us approximately the answer we should expect.

If there are 10 players, then we have 5 pairs of players. Think about any one of those pairs. Since the throws are all independent, it doesn't matter what the first player throws; there is a one-in-six chance that the second player will throw the same number. Since the pair gets one point if the numbers match, the *expected value* in terms of points for a single pair throwing the dice will be 1 point * 1/6 = 1/6 points. Since there are five pairs on the team, the expected value of the team's score for each round will be 5 * 1/6 points = 5/6, or about 0.8333.

When I run your code, I get a value for `mean(scoreA)` of 3.5, so clearly this isn't correct.

A naive implementation that simulates each throw would be:

```r
players_roll_once <- function(players) 
{
  # Ensure that only an even number of players on the team
  if(players %% 2 != 0) stop("Need an even number of players")
  
  # The first member of each pair rolls their dice
  first_members_rolls  <- sample(6, players / 2, replace = TRUE)

  # The second member of each pair rolls their dice
  second_members_rolls <- sample(6, players / 2, replace = TRUE)
  
  # Assign one for each time the first and second member of each pair match
  scored_a_point <- as.numeric(first_members_rolls == second_members_rolls)

  # Add up all the points the team got and return the answer
  return(sum(scored_a_point))
}
```

And we can use the `replicate` function to run the simulation as many times as we like to get `scoreA`:

```r
rolls   <- 100000
players <- 10

set.seed(1) # Makes this reproducible
scoreA  <- replicate(rolls, players_roll_once(players))
```

And the results are:

```r
mean(scoreA)
#> [1] 0.83605

var(scoreA)
#> [1] 0.6985974
```

Comment: @Pops I'm not sure what you mean by the mean and variance of the total score. The expected total score in a single round for ten people (5 pairs of 2) is 5/6. The total score in my example above for 100,000 rounds with 10 people is 83,605. This is a sum, not a mean, and it can't have a variance, since it is only a single number.

Comment: As for the second part of your comment, you could replace the line `scored_a_point <- as.numeric(first_members_rolls == second_members_rolls)` with  `scored_a_point <- first_members_rolls[first_members_rolls == second_members_rolls]`. You will find that the expectation for each round becomes 3.5 * 5/6 or 2.916666...

Comment: @Pops, I'm sorry, I really don't understand what you are asking. I have showed you how to get the mean and variance for the problem you posed in your question. The picture you have posted seems to be discussing a different problem from the one you asked, and includes terms like `k` and `n` that must have been introduced on a previous page. I can only guess to what they refer.

Comment: @Pops I'm afraid I can't access that link from my machine for some reason. I think if you have a different question you want to ask you should probably post a new question, explaining things in enough detail so that people can answer it as-is. If you read the text of the specific question you have asked, I have answered it above. Comments are not a good way to ask complex supplementary questions. Thanks.